# Eloquent Update using ajax not updating

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent

I tried several solutions , this one did work but I can't seem to update the informations being pass.

view.blade.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmUpdate').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // var $Firstname = $('#Firstname').val();
        // var $Lastname = $('#Lastname').val();
        // var $Phone = $('#Phone').val();
        // var $Email = $('#Email').val();
        // var $Address = $('#Address').val();
        // var $username = $('#username').val();

        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.post({
            url:url,
            data:{data},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert("Your Information has been updated.");
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert("Internal Server Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


 <form action="{{ URL::to('/update') }}" method="post" id="frmUpdate">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="{{ Auth::user()->Username }}">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                        <input id="Firstname" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('Firstname') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="{{__('Firstname')}}" name="Firstname" required value="{{ Auth::user()->FirstName }}">
                        @error('Firstname')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="Lastname" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('Lastname') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="{{__('Lastname')}}" name="Lastname" required value="{{ Auth::user()->LastName }}">
                        @error('Lastname')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="Phone" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('Phone') is-invalid @enderror" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" placeholder="{{__('Phone Number')}}" name="Phone" required value="{{ Auth::user()->MobileNum }}">
                        @error('Phone')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <input id="Email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('Email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="{{__('Email')}}" name="Email" required value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">
                        @error('Email')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <textarea id="Address" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('Address') is-invalid @enderror" name="Address" placeholder="{{__('Address')}}" required>{{ Auth::user()->Address }}</textarea>
                        @error('Address')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" id="updateInfo" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Controller.php

```
public function update(Request $request){
        // $this->validate($request,[
        //     'Firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        //     'Lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        //     'Email' => 'required|email',
        //     'Address' => 'required'
        // ]);
        if($request->ajax()){
        $data = [
            'FirstName' => $request->input('Firstname'),
            'LastName' => $request->input('Lastname'),
            'MobileNum' => $request->input('Phone'),
            'email' => $request->input('Email'),
            'Address' => $request->input('Address')
        ];
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->update($request->all());

        // $message = "Your information has been updated!";
        // $request->session()->flash('success', $message);

            return  response(User::find($user->id));
        }
    }
```

as you can see, I tried using the `$data` array but it didn't work instead it passes a null value which is really weird. so i tried  `$request->all()` I saw a tutorial using this so I tried it. it did update but it also did pass null values.

Model.php

```
protected $table = 'tableName';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Username','password','MobileNum','AccountNum','FirstName','LastName','Address','email'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public static function updateData($username,$data){
        User::where('Username', $username)->update($data);
     }
```

Comment: You have to define `fillable` to user model before using mass-assignment for detail check on [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: I already added `flilable` on my model

Comment: Please share user model also.

Comment: just edited it! I'm still looking for solutions right now.

Comment: $user->update($request->all()); seems to be used for mass updates. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

In your case, you maybe should use 

$user->fill($data);

$user->save();

Comment: I get this error using fill `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::fill()`

Comment: @error500 When you call `$user->update()` it just does `$user->fill()->save()` behind the scenes.

Comment: so its okay to use the `update()` function? because `$user->fill()` isn't working on laravel 7 I guess. I always get NULL values, maybe because I wasn't passing any values to my controller, even though I'm using `$request->input()`

Comment: Please can you show your entire form as well. The `fill()` method will work, however, the error suggests that you've started to perform a query on the user model which will return an instance of `Builder` instead.

Comment: I edited and added my form, I tried adding `->first()` to my query. the error is gone but still passes a null value for all my inputs.Is my return value correct?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which parts work, which don't?

Comment: The problem lies on my ajax, since I am using serialize I shouldn't have put it on a curly brackets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main issue here is that you're nesting the data in the ajax call i.e. `data: {data}`. This will mean that the serialized string will be passed as a child attribute of the body rather than the body itself so the server won't parse it.

If you do `dd(request()->input())` you should see something like:

```
"data" => "_token=HICWYthxeeHnUHoWVWhG6xksvKCe6eaAx8vIwnsB&Firstname=Firstname&Lastname=Lastname&Phone=Phone&Email=Email&Address=Address"
```

rather than:

```
"_token" => "HICWYthxeeHnUHoWVWhG6xksvKCe6eaAx8vIwnsB"
"Firstname" => "Firstname"
"Lastname" => "Lastname"
"Phone" => "Phone"
"Email" => "Email"
"Address" => "Address"
```

To get around this don't wrap `data` in `{}` i.e.

```
$.post({
    url: url,
    data: data, //<-- here
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Your Information has been updated.");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Internal Server Error");
    }
});
```

---

In your controller there is no need for `User::find(Auth::user()->id)` as you can simply just do `Auth::user()`. Right now you're basically saying get me the user and then find the user again with the id of the user you've just got for me.

You also don't need to refetch the user as the end of your controller, you can simply return `Auth::user()`.

You controller code could then look something like:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $data = $this->validate($request, [
        'Firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        'Lastname'  => 'required|max:255',
        'Email'     => 'required|email',
        'Address'   => 'required',
        'MobileNum' => 'nullable', //<-- assuming this can be nullable as it wasn't included in your original validation
    ]);

    Auth::user()->fill($data)->save();

    return Auth::user();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I kinda get it now.  so thats why  I get  `"data" => "_token=HICWYthxeeHnUHoWVWhG6xksvKCe6eaAx8vIwnsB&Firstname=Firstname&Lastname=Lastname&Phone=Phone&Email=Email&Address=Address"` , because of the curly brackets. I will use curly brackets when passing values like this `data:{user:user}` right? BTW thank you for helping and explaining it clearly!

Comment: @PlayFree Glad I could help! Yes, that's right. If you want to pass individual attributes you can pass them as an object. You just won't be able to mix the serialized data with it :)